# Difficulties on Understanding different Definitions of a curve

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I do not really understand the connection between these two definitions: A regular simple (smooth) closed  curve is a $ C^1 $-map $ \gamma:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^3 $ with $ \gamma^k(0) = \gamma^k(1) $, k=0,1, $ \gamma'(t) \neq 0$ for all $ t \in [0,1] $ and $\gamma|_{[0,1)} $ is injective. The other definition I encountered is the following: A regular (immersed) simple closed curve is an embedding $ \tilde{\gamma} : S^1 \to R^3 $ with $ \tilde{\gamma}'(t) \neq 0 $ for all $t \in S^1$. I see that there might be an equivalency but how would one write down the connection between these two definitions? I already found a result that states that we can " identify " $ [0,1]$ with $ S^1 $ in the case of closed curves. But how can I derive the other properties? For example, why would be $ \tilde{\gamma} $ be regular if the other representation $ \gamma $ of the curve is regular?

Comment: Do you understand that a function on $S^1$ defines a periodic function on $\Bbb R$ (say, with period $1$) and vice-versa? What does $C^1$ mean in this setting?

Comment: How does a function on S^1 defines a periodic function $ \mathbb{R} $ and vice versa ?

Comment: Hint: Write points of $S^1$ as $e^{2\pi it}$ or as $(\cos 2\pi t,\sin 2\pi t)$.

Comment: Let the function in your hint be defined on R and called e. There is a right-inverse for e, call it f, defined on S^1. If I have a simple closed curve on [0,1] I could define $ γ\circ e\circ f$ to obtain a function on S^1. If the curve is defined on S^1, I could define $γ\circ e $ and get a periodic function on R. Is this correct ?

Comment: The second one is right. The first doesn't work. You just want $\gamma\circ f$, right? Now where do the compatibility conditions come in?

Comment: I am a little bit Confused, why does the function $\gamma \circ f $ have all the properties above ? For example, why is it differentiable ?

Comment: Composition of differentiable functions? If you want to work near $(1,0)\in S^1$, maybe you'd rather change to a different right inverse if it is necessary.